# Listmodelmixin only returns first object when calling self.list(request)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Below is my class code with get method. The problem is if I do not specify `pk`, only one value is being returned. It's not returning the complete list. If I add `pk`, it works fine for every record. What's the issue?

```
class UserGenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin, mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated ]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk=None):
        if pk:
            return Response({
                'data': self.retrieve(request, pk).data
            })

        return self.list(request).data
```

Comment: how did you register this route?

Comment: are you asking about user registration?